# Prove that the following sequence is a cauchy sequence $a_n= \frac{1}{1 \cdot 4} + \frac{1}{4 \cdot 7} +...+ \frac{1}{(1+n) \cdot [1+3(n-1)]}$

Tags: real-analysis

### Prove that the following sequence is a cauchy sequence
$a_n= \frac{1}{1 \cdot 4} + \frac{1}{4 \cdot 7} +...+ \frac{1}{(1+n) \cdot [1+3(n-1)]}$

Let $\varepsilon >0$ there exists $N \in \Bbb N$ such that for all $m,n > N$ the absolute difference $|a_n - a_m| < \varepsilon$

I assumed $n>m$ and took the general sequence $a_n = \frac{1}{(1+n) \cdot [1+3(n-1)]}$ and $a_m = \frac{1}{(1+m) \cdot [1+3(m-1)]}$

$|a_n-a_m| = \sum_{k=m+1}^n \frac{1}{(1+3k)(1+3(k-1))}$ and $(1+3k[1+3(k-1)]) \geq 1+3k$ so now we can start comparing

$|a_n-a_m| = \sum_{k=m+1}^n \frac{1}{(1+3k)(1+3(k-1))} \leq \sum_{k=m+1}^n \frac{1}{1+3k} < \sum_{k=m+1}^n \frac{1}{3k}$

now we have $\frac{1}{3(m+1)} + \frac{1}{3(m+2)} + ... + \frac{1}{3n} < \frac{1}{m+1} + \frac{1}{m+2} + ... + \frac{1}{n}$

and since $n,m >N$

$\frac{1}{m+1} + \frac{1}{m+2} + ... + \frac{1}{n} < \frac{1}{N+1} + \frac{1}{N+2} + ... + \frac{1}{N} < \frac{1}{N} + \frac{1}{N} + ... + \frac{1}{N}$

$= \frac {n-m-1}{N} < \frac{n}{N} < \varepsilon$

lastly I choose $N= \lceil \frac {n}{ \varepsilon} \rceil$

I am not sure of what I did and if it is correct as I am still new to this concept so any help and tips is appreciated!

Comment: Your estimate is not good enough. Better write $\sum_{k=m+1}^n \frac{1}{(1+3k)(1+3(k-1))} \leq \sum_{k=m+1}^n \frac{1}{9 k (k-1)}$ ...

Comment: Easy solution: Compare $\sum \frac 1 {(1+n)[1+3(n-1)]}$ with $\sum \frac 1 {n^{2}}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The estimate
$$
 |a_n - a_m | \le \sum_{k=m+1}^n \frac{1}{3k}
$$
*cannot* be good enough to prove that $(a_n)$ is a Cauchy sequence because the series $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{3k}$ diverges. The formal error in your proof is that $N= \lceil \frac {n}{ \varepsilon} \rceil$ depends on $n$.

If you estimate
$$
 |a_n - a_m | \le \sum_{k=m+1}^n \frac{1}{9 k (k-1)} = \frac 19 \sum_{k=m+1}^n \left( \frac{1}{k-1} - \frac 1k\right) = \frac 19 \left( \frac 1m - \frac 1n \right) \le \frac{1}{9N}
$$
for $n > m > N$ instead then things become much simpler.

Comment: thank you it is now understandable, just a simple question.. I am wondering how you got to the inequality $9k(k-1)$

Comment: @Adamrk: $(1+3k) \cdot (1+3(k-1)) > (3k) \cdot (3(k-1)) = 9k(k-1)$